# Como buscar dados em JSON nesse código específico

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, array

Preciso fazer exatamente o mesmo solicitado nesse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77037/busca-em-json-com-ajax-em-campo-espec%C3%ADfico), pegar dados Json e retornar em um campo específico. O usuário Jeffson Silva fez exatamente o que preciso e disponibilizou nesse [Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/28j8Lxrq/2/).

Só que esbarrei no seguinte problema: Não consigo buscar os dados em um Json externo para "var dados = [].

Tentei usar `"$.getJSON("dados.json", function (data) {..."` Mas não dá certo buscar esse dados.
Quando é  colocado o os dados do array manualmente dentro de `"var dados = []"`, funciona mas, quando tenta buscar esses dados externamento, não está dando certo.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz e mostrar como fazer isso usando esse código de [Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/28j8Lxrq/2/)?

Desde já obrigado

Comment: Esse link que indicaste tem um JSON inválido. Falta-lhe o último `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os browsers modernos bloqueiam requisições assíncronas cross-domain (entre domínios diferentes). Porém existe um "hack" para burlar isso, é uma técnica de transmissão de dados chamada **jsonp**.

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70267/o-que-%C3%A9-o-jsonp-e-como-funciona) você pode ver a explicação do que é, e [nesse link](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/) você vê como fazer requisições jsonp com ajax. Será necessário modificar a saída do seu servidor também.

Se você rodar o script dentro do domínio em que o json está sendo buscado não encontrará esse problema.

Comment: o arquivo Json está no mesmo servidor, porém,  não testei o código que citei acima no meu código oficial e sim somente no JSfiddle, será que é por isso que não funcionou?